# How to measure fragmentation in OSX and WIN

Tags: c, windows, macos, winapi, memory-fragmentation

Our clients experience [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) in some specific scenarios and we can't pinpoint any memory leaks so we would like to understand if it's a memory fragmentation issue.

There are a lot of different memory metrics in both OSX and WIN (resident, dirty, working set, reserved, committed, ...) and we can't figure out which metrics we can use to measure fragmentation.

`vmmap` command in OSX presents a fragmentation column and it seems to be measured as follows :

```
(DIRTY+SWAP FRAG SIZE) = DIRTY SIZE - BYTES ALLOCATED

FRAG = (DIRTY+SWAP FRAG SIZE) / DIRTY SIZE x 100.0
```

[image]

The question is how we can retrieve `DIRTY SIZE` and `BYTES ALLOCATED` ?

There is [mstats](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/gen/malloc.c) which gives the amount of memory allocated and used via `malloc` but the reported values doesn't match anything we see in vmmap.

[image]

WIN is also a totally different story. We had a look at the following values but we don't know if they can be used to measure fragmentation:

```
static void vminfo (unsigned long *free, unsigned long *reserved, unsigned long *committed) {
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memory_info;
    memory_info.BaseAddress = 0;
    *free = *reserved = *committed = 0;
    while (VirtualQuery (memory_info.BaseAddress, &memory_info, sizeof (memory_info))) {
        switch (memory_info.State) {
        case MEM_FREE:
            *free += memory_info.RegionSize;
            break;
        case MEM_RESERVE:
            *reserved += memory_info.RegionSize;
            break;
        case MEM_COMMIT:
            *committed += memory_info.RegionSize;
            break;
        }
        memory_info.BaseAddress = (char *) memory_info.BaseAddress + memory_info.RegionSize;
    }
}
```

We also had a look at [GetProcessMemoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo) and same story, we don't know if and how  values from [PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-process_memory_counters_ex) can be used to measure fragmentation.

TLDR : How can we measure fragmentation in OSX and WIN ?

Comment: In windows this is not memory fragmentation issue, but your app allocate to many memory. Probably because not free memory after it no more need. So will be huge size of mem_commit with faster mem_private type. Then may be, if not allocate virtual memory direct, more info you get from enum heaps and it blocks

Comment: @RbMm Can you please tell me how did you decide that it is not a fragmentation issue in Windows ? The amount of information about fragmentation in Windows is really scarce, that makes me think that fragmentation in 64 bit WIN is never an issue in practice, is that true ?

Comment: In 64bit windows , because it have huge virtual space, fragmentation never can be problem. In 32bit it hypothetical can be problem, if you allocate huge memory chunks. More than 100-200 mb.. but i very doubt that your app do this. In another case - i not understand how fragmentation can be a problem - you try say that exist enough memory in your process for block which you want allocate, but not exist big enough contiguous chunk ?! Not believe in this and you can easy check that this is false. Simply look for mem_free blocks. What is maximum block size and total size

Comment: Windows uses a [low-fragmentation heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/low-fragmentation-heap) by default starting with Windows Vista. I doubt that you'll ever run out of memory due to fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

(DIRTY+SWAP) FRAG SIZE = (DIRTY+SWAP) - ALLOCATED

(DIRTY+SWAP) FRAG SIZE / (DIRTY+SWAP) x 100.0 = % FRAG

(DIRTY+SWAP) = footprint